# Runtime Error : Unknown parameter

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have creared a class which is called "AttackInjection". I defined a variable (type bool) in that class that is, "propagationDelay_attackInjection". I called that variable in the ChannelAccess class (ChannelAccess.cc).

When i run the simulation, i received the following error.

**A runtime error occured:
(veins::AttackInjection): Unknown parameter
'propagationDelay_attackInjection' -- in module (veins::PhyLayer80211p)
Highway.node[2].nic.phy80211p(id=36),at t=1.113578s, event #123**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWGGX.jpg)

Could you help me understanding what am i missing or what wrong am i doing?

Thanks in advance,

Best wishes,
/MM

Answer (score 1):

OMNeT++ parameters are not the same as member variables of a class. OMNeT++ parameters are declared in `.ned` files, member variables are declared in `.h` files. For more details refer to the [OMNeT++ manual entry on parameters](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:parameters).